# How to download the latest version of Android SDK for Visual Studio .NET 2017

Tags: android, visual-studio, sdk, android-sdk-manager

I would like to make use of the latest version of Android SDK, but it doesn't show up in "Android SDKs and Tools".

[image: Android SDKs and Tools]

I'm using MS Visual Studio Professional 2017, and I have to use Google repository, because it doesn't work with Microsoft repository. Can you advise?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Microsoft Visual Studio`, I assume that you are or planning to work with `Xamarin`, and since you're asking for advice, I'd recommend that you work with android sdk from Microsoft repository instead of Google's as its clearly shown in the screenshot **"unsupported"**.
However, if you still want to get latest sdk tool, switch to tab **"Tools"** instead of **"Platforms"** you'll see all the version and from there you can update as needed.